# Can not connect to remote phpmyadmin with c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to connect to my remote mysql database with c# application.

I'm opening the phpmyadmin interface with http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/
But when I try to connect to this db with application, I got some errors.

My connection string is:

```
server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=*****;pwd=*******;database=db_sample;
```

I used MySqlConnector. And here my error:

> Additional information: Can not established the connection MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I'm not sure about my connection string. When i google it, mysql connection strings are seems like that. By the way I create a new user for remote access and gave all permissions.

Could you help on this issue, how can i connect to db.

Thank you

Comment: Usually this means that you haven't granted the permissions for your user to connect FROM the machine where your code is running

Comment: Check also firewalls settings in relation to the default port used by MySql 3306

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application to help you manage a MySQL or MariaDB database, it's not a database itself. Just because your phpMyAdmin can be reached from a particular machine doesn't mean the database is on the same machine or that the database daemon is listening for external connections. You'll have to check your database to make sure it's properly configured to allow external connections and that there's no firewall or other device blocking incoming connections.